boost::interprocess in mixed 32-bit/64-bit environment
On the surface it seems simple: use your own specialization of offset_ptr that will be compatible with both and use it message_queue specialization instead of defaults.
However, I see a ton of default rb_tree_best_fit objects in the boost code itself that would not be compatible with mixed environment.
It seems that the only feasible way to achieve interoperability is to override defaults in config, are there better ways to address this issue?
